# How can I attach an Event to an element of a parent frame in javascript?

Tags: javascript, parent, frame, attachevent

I want to attach an 'onclick' event in a link element in my editor.

I did this:

```
parent.document.frames["myframe"].document.body.attachEvent('onmouseover', function(e) { 
        parent.document.frames["myframe"].document.getElementsByTagName("a").attachEvent('onclick', function(e) { 
            alert("Hello");
        });
 });
```

but it doesn't work. I want this one to work in IE and I am using Javascript.
Does anyone know what is wrong with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did with jQuery finally:

```
  parent.document.frames["myframe"].document.body.attachEvent('onmouseover', function(e) { 
        $("a",parent.document.frames["myframe"].document).click(function(event){
             alert("hello");
        });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching the mouseover event to a surrounding div rather then the body.

Comment: I don't have a surrounding div, it is only the body. The mouseover event works ok, the onclick event doesn;t work.